# Series integral relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I know there is some relation between a series and and integral and I know it's something like this

$$\sum ^{m}_{n=k} f( n) =\int^{m}_{k} f\left(\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor }\right) dx$$

I tried looking up relations between integrals and summations multiple times, but I couldn't find anything on this particular topic.  I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: What you wrote looks almost right, but I'm not sure why the $\frac 1 {\lfloor x \rfloor}$ is not just $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $m$ isn't $m+1$?

Comment: Oh This seems to be the answer $\sum ^{k}_{n=m} f( n) =\int\limits ^{k}_{m} f(\lfloor x\rfloor ) dx$. Thank you!

Comment: @Highvoltagemath Your stated answer in the comment above is not quite correct. As dskeletov's comment stated, the upper limit of the integral should be $1$ more than that of the summation. For example, with your formula, if $m = k$, the LHS would be $f(m)$ but the RHS would always be $0$. As such, using your notation, it should be $\sum_{n=m}^{k} f(n) = \int_{m}^{k+1} f(\lfloor x \rfloor)dx$ instead.